# compile can't find GL lib

Tags: compiling, gcc, opengl, mesa

```
bjorn@bjorn-031:~/samples/SOP$ gcc -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

I've installed libglu1-mesa-dev and rebooted. I'm using Nvidia drivers.

This output look strange to me though:

```
ldconfig -v 
...
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa:
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Cannot stat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so: No such file or directory
...
```

Comment: Required : lib**gl**1-mesa-dev

Comment: This was already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by fixing symbolic links as described here:
http://techtidings.blogspot.se/2012/01/problem-with-libglso-on-64-bit-ubuntu.html

As I also needed the -lGLU so I had to repeat the process for libGLU.so. My actual lib file were called "libGLU.so.1.3.1" so I had to do:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so
```